# monotouch implement singleton Admob ads

Tags: xamarin.ios, admob

I am trying to implement Admob ads in my App.

After a few tests I made with previous apps, i have realized that a static Ad between screens usually make a better eCPM.

So I have searched a bit and found a post on implementing a singleton for Admob -  unfortunetally it's written in objective-C. 
I wonder if someone implemented something similar in monotouch or maybe implemented something which will get the same result.

This is the relevant post:
[Creating A GADBannerView Singleton in AdMob Applications](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just make a static variable using `Lazy<T>`:

```
private static Lazy<GADBannerView> _adBanner = new Lazy<GADBannerView>(() => new GADBannerView());

public static GADBannerView AdBanner
{
    get { return _adBanner.Value; }
}
```

You could put this in your `AppDelegate`, or just in a static class.

Comment: If someone read it in the future it works great, but I needed to add somewhere in my code 
LoadRequest (GADRequest.Request);
For the Ad to appear.
e.g: AdmobManager.AdBanner.LoadRequest (GADRequest.Request);